# Why does PowerShell' ignore the `ErrorAction` parameter when attempting to resolve the home path?

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-core

What's explains the difference in error handling behaviour between these two actions?

1. attempting to resolve a path that doesn't exist; and
2. attempting to resolve the home path when it isn't set?

```sh
❯ # given we're not in the filesystem, e.g:
❯ cd alias:
❯ $PWD.Provider | select Name, Home # so the Home path is not set

Name  Home
----  ----
Alias

❯ resolve-path doesnotexist # error
Resolve-Path: Cannot find path 'Alias:\doesnotexist' because it does not exist.

❯ resolve-path doesnotexist -ErrorAction Ignore # no error

❯ resolve-path ~ # error
Resolve-Path: Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Alias').Home = 'path'".

❯ resolve-path ~ -ErrorAction Ignore # also an error
Resolve-Path: Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Alias').Home = 'path'".

❯ # also...
❯ $error.Clear()
❯ $ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'
❯ resolve-path ~ # no error in console but...
❯ $error

Resolve-Path: Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Alias').Home = 'path'".

❯ $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.1.3
```

Why doesn't `ErrorAction -Ignore` work when the path being resolved starts with `~`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. How did you set `$PWD` so that it has a `Home` property. With PowerShell on Windows (Desktop & Core) `$PWD` should be of type `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` which doesn't have any `Home` property.

Comment: @pwnosh It looks like `cd HKLM:` is missing from the start.

Comment: @pwnosh sorry, my bad. as @don says, pretty much any provider other than `FileSystem` doesn't have a default home. `Home` is a property of the provider, not the path. I'll update the question.

Comment: @DonCruickshank. Thanks. I also did miss the Provider property yesterday, sorry. Well I'm still not sure, but at least I guess I found the source of the exception. It's `GetHomeRelativePath`, see: ( https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/search?q=HomePathNotSet ). The process also tries to expand the environment variable `env:__SuppressAnsiEscapeSequences` when we have no home directory set, see `Trace-Command -PSHost -Name LocationGlobber, PathResolution, PSDriveInfo {Resolve-Path ~ }`

Comment: Yeah, I'd come to the same place :D

The `LocationGlobber` seems to throw an `InvalidOperationException` when home isn't set vs an `ItemNotFound` when it simply can't resolve the given path. Are these handled differently for some reason?